# Why are records shown in the wrong language after upgrading to TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

After upgrading an installation from TYPO3 8 to TYPO3 9.5.5 and switching language configuration to sites (no more `config.*language*` in TypoScript), I do get some internationalization errors, mainly records displayed in the wrong language:

- For a table which has a relation to categories, I do get some records displayed in translated form for a page in default language.
- Powermail (upgraded from 6.2 to 7.2) shows a similar behaviour I think: Some field labels are shown in their translated versions (and, contrary to the category relation, no labels at all are loaded in the non-default language).

I have tested settings `config.sys_language_overlay` to `0`, `1` and `hideNonTranslated` and `config.tx_extbase.persistence.consistentTranslationOverlayHandling` to `0` without success.

After multiple days of debugging and stepping through code I still do not have any idea where the error could be or which settings I should look into; any hints in that direction would be appreciated. I am also a bit unsure about what multilingual M:M relations (for the categories) should look like in the database and how they are supposed to work in ExtBase, but the behavior on 8.x was fine.

Comment: do you have run all steps in the installtool -> upgrade wizard? the fill l10 translation field could be missing in your case.

Comment: Could you provide the TCA of the parent records and those related items, since it might be a problem that was already there with CMS 8 but either ignored or corrected by different language handling methods.